# R: print ID value if a certain number is not found in the corresponding rows

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| id | score |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| x | 2 |
| x | 3 |
| y | 1 |
| y | 2 |
| y | 3 |
| ... |  |

I want to check if every ID has 1, 2 and 3 in the "score" column. If some of the IDs doesn't have either 1, 2 or 3, I want to save them to a vector.

I tried to somehow loop it / write a condition in dplyr but failed:

````
  group_by(id) %>% 
  {if(!1 %in% score | !2 %in% score | !3 %in% score ) {print(id)}}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', `filter` by creating a logical vector, and wrapping `all` i.e. if all the 1, 2, 3 are in the 'score', then we negate (`!`) to filter only those groups that doesn't comply with it, get the `distinct` 'id' and `pull` as a `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(!all(c(1, 2, 3) %in% score)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    distinct(id) %>%
    pull(id)
```

-output

```
> v1
[1] "z"
```

NOTE: `print` just prints the output in the console and doesn't have a return value.  We may need to store in an object

---

In the OP's code, the condition argument with `if` is outside the tidyverse functions and `score` is not an object in the global env, instead it is a column in the data.  We may use `.$` or `.[[` to extract, but that will also lose the grouping attribute.  It is better to do this within tidyverse functions i.e. `filter` or `summarise` etc.  Or we may use `group_modify` to do the `print` based on the OP's code

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   group_modify(~ {if(!1 %in% .x$score | !2 %in% .x$score | 
       !3 %in% .x$score ) {
            print(.y$id)
      }
    .x})
[1] "z"
# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
  id    score
  <chr> <int>
1 x         1
2 x         2
3 x         3
4 y         1
5 y         2
6 y         3
7 z         1
8 z         2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z"), 
    score = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```